# Proplema con layout: Widget no se redimensiona con la ventana

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4

Tengo un `Dialog` con un único `Wigdet`que ocupa toda la ventana. En este caso es un `QTextEdit`y está creado con `Qt Designer`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el fichero en `Python`:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Dialog"))
        Dialog.resize(400, 300)
        self.gridLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout(Dialog)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("gridLayout"))
        self.textEdit = QtGui.QTextEdit(Dialog)
        self.textEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("textEdit"))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.textEdit, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog", None))
```

Sin embargo al ejecutar el código que lanza del `Dialog` no se redimensiona el `Widget`.

```
import sys

from qtdesigner.dialog_reacciones_rsa import *

class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):

        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.textEdit.setText('Hola\nAdios')


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = Window()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Editado el 21.06.2018**

Modifico el código del `Dialog`según comentario de FJSevilla:

```
...
class Window(QtGui.QDialog):

        def __init__(self, parent=None):

            QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
...
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Pedro ¿Por qué creas un `QDialog` en QtDesigner y luego en `Window` heredas de `QMainWindows` en vez de `QDialog`?

Comment: Vale, gracias @FJSevilla. ¡Eso era!

Answer (score 0):

Si necesita usar QMainWindow

Lo siento, uso PyQt5:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

#from qtdesigner.dialog_reacciones_rsa import *
# Tengo `dialog_reacciones_rsa.py` en el directorio actual
from dialog_reacciones_rsa import Ui_Dialog

class Window(QMainWindow, Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)   

        self.central_widget = QWidget()                 # definir el widget central
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)      # instalar QMainWindow.centralWidget
        self.centralWidget().setLayout(self.gridLayout) # agregar el diseño al widget central        

        self.textEdit.setHtml(""" 
                Hola<br><b>Adios</b><br><br>

                <p style="color: red; font: 15px;">Atención: por favor mira `dialog_reacciones_rsa.py`:</p>
                <span style="color: blue; font: 12px;">
                <br>...<br>
                #self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(Dialog)<br>
                self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()<br>
                ...</span>
                """)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = Window()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

dialog_reacciones_rsa.py

```
#from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
#                                ^^^^^^^^^

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtWidgets.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtWidgets.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtWidgets.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Dialog"))
        Dialog.resize(400, 300)

        # !!!!!!!!!!!!!!                         vvvvvv
        #self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(Dialog)
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()     


        self.gridLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("gridLayout"))
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Dialog)
        self.textEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("textEdit"))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.textEdit, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog", None))
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]